# How far do I have to walk to hit level 10 Survival?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

For the `Survival Expert` trophy, I have to hit level 10 in Survival, which levels up by traveling on foot. I'm on chapter 8 and I'm about halfway from level 5 to 6. It goes up very slowly so I'm curious if there's an estimate on how far I have to run/walk in order to reach level 10.

Comment: I'm level 6 in chapter 3... do I walk way too much or do you not walk at all...?

Comment: @sevenseacat holy crap, I walk literally everywhere under a mile away. Earlier I walked from Hammerhead to Galdin Quay so now I'm level 6. Do you do all of the side quests?

Comment: that would have taken forever o_o

Comment: @sevenseacat yeah it took quite a while. I had to set up camp twice and I spent an entire night fishing, lol.

Comment: Isn't Survival supposed to level up after battles, when Gladiolus loots things?

Comment: @lentinant no, that's the benefit. You level it up by walking.

Comment: ....The demo ruined me into walking everywhere.  I keep forgetting the car exists.  Haha.  As a sidenote, if you are running around, everywhere, (And not wearing free-running outfit), make sure you turn on your stamina bar, in the settings.  If you release, and re-tap, your sprint key right as you are about to run out of stamina, you will phase, and reset your stamina bar, allowing you to sprint indefinitely.

Comment: I am in chapter 15, am level 96, and have completed ALMOST every sidequest so far, and my survival is only level 6. I did make use of fast travel and my chocobos whenever possible however, as I am an impatient person. Still, ive completed every dungeon, every special boss(except for the mazes which im about to start) and almost every quest.

Comment: This turned out to be the last trophy I needed to get for platinum. Even after walking everywhere reasonably close, I was only level 8 after completing the main story. Several real-world hours of nothing but walking were required to get from 9 to 10, and I ended up going around most of the world map several times... walking from Hammerhead, to Galdin Quay, then to Ravatogh, then to the Vesperpool, then to Lestallum...

Comment: I rubber banded my controller while I slept and it only went from almost to 8 to halfway to 9. Granted I sleep a maximum of 6 hours usually. I finished getting to 10 while I was at work (9 hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About 315 miles or so.**

Method: Assuming Shawn Gordon's source is correct and you will have to walk for 30 hours to get to level 10, we can use that to figure out how *far* you have to walk. All we need is to figure out how fast Noctis walks and then to do a bit of math.

I parked my car at Coernix Station and then ran SW down the road so that I'd have a straight path free of obstacles to walk. Parking my car at the station gave me a marker with a distance on it. I walked until just after the marker ticked up to .35 miles, so that it wouldn't actually be .359 miles or something like that. (I'm assuming it rounds down.) I walked as straight and steadily as I could to the marker, and it took me almost exactly two minutes.

Multiplying .35 miles per 2 minutes against 1800 minutes in 30 hours gets us about 315 miles. It might be a bit more than this if I didn't walk perfectly straight, but it should be pretty close.

Comment: That is a good way to find the distance! Unfortunately I can't confirm or deny the 30 hour mark, as I've since rubber banded my controller and don't know how long/far I walked to get to level 10.

Answer (score 0):

*Hauntress* from [iTechPost](http://www.itechpost.com/articles/62838/20161207/final-fantasy-xv-guide-rank-up-max-out-fishing-cooking.htm) writes:

> Survival for Gladiolus increases when you've walked a certain distance
>   and leveling this skill could take quite a long time. There are two
>   methods you can do, the easiest of which is you can take a rubber band
>   and strap it around your left and right controller stick so Noctis
>   will keep running in circles. You can let it sit there for 30 hours
>   and you will reach rank 10. The fastest way (20 hours) is method two...

And because in the wee parts of the mind, I can hear a follow up - how does it calculate the distance traveled and how much actual time will this devour, I found this little nugget...

*Taipei Kindom* posted on [TrueAchievements.com](https://www.trueachievements.com/a226621/survival-expert-achievement):

> ...For all the method I've tested, it only matters how many steps you
>   travel. There is no difference between running on the asphalt and the
>   field. It counts the length of your rout[sic], not the point to point
>   straight distance.

Running a longer test but using the same method as Kat and using the same general consensus on the Internet of 30 hours to max the skill, I figured Noctis' base walk / jog speed to 4.2 mph by jogging on the road through brush for 5 minutes from dead stop and checked my distance was .35 miles.

At 4.2 miles per hour for 30 hours, it puts the distance walked closer to 125 miles.

Unlike Kat I didn't ensure I was free of obstacles because unless the banding trick is used, the real-world scenario would have minor setbacks from obstacles.

Finally, how the reward drops are calculated is covered by
[Samurai Gamers](https://samurai-gamers.com/final-fantasy-15-ffxv/survival-skill-final-fantasy-15-ffxv/)

> p = (10 + Skill Level)/100
>
> As you take more steps between each battle, you will have a greater
>   chance of obtaining an item as a reward. The number of times the game
>   does this calculation (n) is expressed as:
>
> n = (Current Step Total – Step Total After Previous Battle) x 0.01
>
> This means that the game processes the p calculation n times. This
>   stops as soon as you obtain an item through the skill. Only one item
>   will obtained per battle. The final item reward probability r for each
>   battle is expressed as:
>
> r = 1 – (1 – p)n

Comment: Someone needs to figure out how fast Noctis walks and convert the time to a distance.

Comment: That's going to reguire knowing scale

Comment: The game gives distances so that part should be easy. I might do it later.

Comment: Given that it uses the length of route and not the p2p distance, is the calculation going to be overly useful to find more than time spent? and if so, how much time will you spend calculating time spent running?

Comment: I'll find a parking spot at the end of a straight section of road and park there. That'll give me a distance when I stand at my starting point.  So long as I can find a decently long straight section, it should be fairly accurate. Idk how useful it will be to know, but that's what the question asks, and I have to run for ages to get the skill up anyway. (Even though Venomous has since cheated their way to level 10, I'm curious myself just how far it is.)

Comment: I think first you have to determine if the running is calculated like the Chocobo distance is calculated - distance or time, because the Chocobo calculation is about time mounted and you have to calculate starting from a 0 time and distance to hope to be accurate, mainly because to attain the next level, the time requirement increases (therefore, distance increases - and I dont imagine the game would deploy different distance calculation methods)  You planning on starting a New Game from start to find the specifics?

Comment: Oh no, nothing like that. I'm assuming your given 30 hours to walk to level 10 is correct, so I'm just figuring out how many mph Noctis can walk, then calculating how far he can walk in 30 hours.

Comment: What makes you think his run speed is 7.5 mph? Unless you're sprinting the whole way, I don't think he jogs that quickly.

Comment: I run a 5 minute mile, which is about 14mph and that's not my full tilt sprint - which is to say 7.5mph  isn't very fast... That aside, I noticed Noctis' normal run is about half that of a Chocobo. A Chocobo at start is around 15 (given it levels up to 20 and then about 30), so if Noctis' is half as fast as a Chocobo....

Comment: No...Bad math, a 5 minute mile is 12mph (11.9)....So...Noctis' speed would be more like 6mph

Comment: @Venomous my timed answer gives a walk (not sprint) speed of 10 mph which does seem high, even for a jog. So who knows.

Comment: I just redid a test using Kat's method but on brush, and got some wierd numbers... Walk/jog at 4.2mph over .35 mi, and five minutes time. That's 126 miles in 30 hours... This is confusing.