# How many fish does Noctis need to catch?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

In Final Fantasy 15, Noctis' skill is fishing. How many total fish does he need to catch to reach level 10, and do different fish give different experience points when caught?

Comment: Related: [Do different dishes give more cooking experience?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/295142/124566). While it is a good question, it would be very difficult to calculate that information. This would require a lot of patience to catch one fish, camp, tally up XP. Rinse and repeat

Comment: Also related: [How far do I have to walk to hit level 10 Survival?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/293443/how-far-do-i-have-to-walk-to-hit-level-10-survival)

Comment: I don't understand how the miles walked question relates.

Comment: @ShawnGordon: I assume relates in this case doesn't mean "Helps answer the question" but that if you are wondering how to max out one skill then you may well be wondering how to max out the others too.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really possible to answer with a concrete number, as different fish *do* reward more or less experience.

This is referenced in [this article](http://www.itechpost.com/articles/62838/20161207/final-fantasy-xv-guide-rank-up-max-out-fishing-cooking.htm):

> Fishing for Noctis increases every time he catches a fish. The best place to fish is at Vesperpool since it offers a lot of rare fish types; the bigger and rarer the fish you catch, the bigger boost you'll have.

It's also mentioned [here](http://www.rpgsite.net/feature/5109-final-fantasy-xv-guide-how-to-fish-properly-to-raise-your-fishing-level-and-earn-ap-quickly):

> Each fish in the game has a specific experience and AP bonus associated with it, so do your best to track down all the fish in the game!

Thus, it depends on what kind of fish you're catching, but if you do all of your fishing from 1-10 at the Vesperpool, you'll probably need to catch somewhere around 150-200 fish, if I had to give a specific numerical range. However, you probably won't be doing all your fishing there, so your number will differ greatly.